# Нужно ли ставить атрибут unsigned ключам таблиц?

Tags: mysql, sql

Ключи таблиц (id) в автоинкрементом начинаются с 1. Тогда есть смысл ставить у всех ID атрибут unsigned. Но есть сомнения что так не делают. Как правильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ: и да и нет. Всё зависит от того, что вы планируете хранить в этом поле. Каждый числовой тип имеет ограничение по числу значений, которые в поле этого типа можно хранить. Это хорошо видно в таблице к статье в мануале - [11.2.1 Integer Types (Exact Value) - INTEGER, INT, SMALLINT, TINYINT, MEDIUMINT, BIGINT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html).

Рассмотрим, например, тип `TINYINT`. Для его хранения выделен 1 байт. Или 8 бит. А 8 бит, если посчитать, это ровно 256 уникальных значений (2 в степени 8). А вот дальше два варианта развития событий:

Если вам нужны только неотрицательные значения, то вы просто получаете в своё распоряжение все эти 256 неотрицательных значений: `от 0 до 255`.

Если вам нужны и отрицательные значения тоже, то первый бит (крайний слева) будет отвечать за знак числа (плюс или минус). А значит для хранения самого значения у вас остается ещё 7 бит, а это (2 в степени 7) 128 уникальных значений. 128 меньше нуля: `от -128 до -1`; и 128 с противоположной стороны оси значений включая ноль: `от 0 до +127`.

Базе данных всё равно что и как хранить. И по какому значению ключа объединять строки в запросах. Всё зависит от ваших потребностей. Устраивают вас отрицательные ключи? Берите отрицательные. Нет? Сделайте их неотрицательными.

Answer (score 0):

При `INT[(M)] [UNSIGNED]` увеличивается диапазон длины с максимальной `2147483647` до `4294967295`. Учитывая это и что это поле `ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT`, логичнее ставить.

Это общая рекомендация при проектирование базы данных. Но это на ваше усмотрение.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/354042)

Comment: @KirillKorushkin так норм?ъ